# "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data"

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to use Google Spreadsheets but I get this error when an `IMPORTXML` would overwrite some rows of cells that already has something in them:

**Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data**

In the old Google Spreadsheets we had the `EXPAND` function which took care of that, but now it's gone.

Is there a way to force an overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just met the same issue today. I have fixed it by using the `UNIQUE` function.

**Original formula:**

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Septemeber!J:J,Septemeber!C:C=A398))
```

I had duplicated values in `Septemeber!J:J`. The formula returned this error:

```
Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C394
```

**Working formula using `UNIQUE`:**

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(Septemeber!J:J,Septemeber!C:C=A398)))
```